# N before object/table name etc in system stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am fully understand the role of the N' before - by example - like N'%K' when we put query to nvarchar column, but I definitely don't understand why it's required (?), when it comes to name of the object in system stored procedure. I have book T-Sql fundamentals by Itzik Ben Gan and I see this code:

```
exec sys.sp_help
@objname = N'Sales.Orders';
```

or

```
exec sys.sp_help
@table_name = N'Orders',
@table_owner = N'Sales';
```

Why do we need to put the N before objname?

Comment: What makes you think it's somehow different to what you already fully understand?

Comment: Oh, so it's all about the name of the table etc can be in Unicode, so just to 'prevent' we use N before actual name? Well, to be honest, I thought that you can't name table, schema name etc with charcters which are not part of the Latin1_General.

Comment: Yep, check the rules for [Regular Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-2017#rules-for-regular-identifiers) (And the rest of that page for info regarding collations)

Comment: Oh, so looks like sometimes I try to overcomplicate things, but it's so simple. Thanks, have a nice day!

Comment: @Karol . . . If it is any consolation, I don't understand why it is required either.  It would seem that SQL Server should be able to convert the string to a unicode string.  Apparently, though, that is not something the parser does.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it's probably in the name of being specific, for a world that cares (whether or not it should) about how many bytes are used to represent what is seen on screen